# Using an analytical balance (0.0000 precision) to measure µg (micrograms)?

Tags: lab-techniques, measurement

If i needed to prepare 200µg/ml of proteinase K, and the proteinase K  was in a solid powder form, would I  have to weight out 200 µg using an analytical balance, and if so, is it possible with a balance that only goes up to four decimal places? (i.e. 0.0000) I assumed 1 microgram is 1×10<sup>-6</sup> gram and therefore 0.000001 gram.

Comment: How is this a biology question? If you are interested in the finer points of using a balance, you might enjoy reading this: [A question of balance](http://academy.chromatographyonline.com/lcgc/article/articleDetail.jsp?id=311444)

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, that mass is too small to measure with a standard analytical scale. There are two options you could use:

1. Make a larger volume of your 200 ug/mL solution.
2. Make a concentrated stock such as 20 mg/mL. This a 100X stock; you can make 1 mL of 200 ug/mL proteinase K with 10 uL of stock and 990 uL of buffer. Small volumes are easier to measure than small masses (with a micropipette).

Comment: I guess i still am having issues with the concepts of concentrations. It is just such a hard concept to wrap my head around, i wish i could have practice with it.  For your first option, making a larger volume, what would that entail? The recipe requires 200ug/ml , so i wouldnt know how to deal with anything else. For the second option, how would i go about making the 20mg/ml stock? Would I measure out 20miligrams of the powder = 0.020grams on the scale? And then mix that with 1 ml of water? But even with that more concentrated stock, i dont understand how i go from the 20mg/ml to the 200ug/ul

Comment: @RoSiv You should practice. I imagine your teacher could help you and there are many resources on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

In this case make a large quantity and store it as stock - this is a general lab practice. Preparing 10 ml of your protK solurion would you need 2000ug (=2mg) of protK powder.